# How to get required values from dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the next function:

```
def render(self, src, **kwargs):
    dict = self._tree_read(src, self.src_tree_path)
```

dict contains:

```
[('hosts', [{'username': 'test-user', 'url': 'http://example.com', 'hostname': 'test-host'}, {'username': 'test-user2', 'url': 'http://example.com2', 'hostname': 'test-host2'}])]
```

Then I'm trying to run another bash script and pass arguments from dict to it(I have 2 configurations in dict, so I need to run subprocess 2 times):

```
subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "/opt/hosts.sh", "username", "url", "hostname"], shell=False)
```

but without success, please help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are calling `dict` is actually a list, containing a tuple, that has a list of dicts in it.

First off, `dict` is a built-in, don't override it, call that variable something else.

From there, you can iterate over those results to run that subprocess multiple times with the values you want.

```
def render(self, src, **kwargs):
   results = self._tree_read(src, self.src_tree_path)

   for host in result[0][1]:
      subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "/opt/hosts.sh", host["username"], host["url"], host["hostname"]], shell=False)
```